# Does spark dataframe.filter(...).select(...) use sequential search or hash algorithms?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Scenario: I have a lookup table created (input is JSON file of around 50 Mb) and cached in memory so that it can be looked up while processing each row of the input file (around 10000 data points in each input file).

Problem: Does dataframe.filter(...).select(...) method in spark perform a sequential search or hash search? How can we retrieve data faster in this case? Also, I was wondering if i need to create a index on it or create a hash table of it (if i need to, i am not sure how its done for dataframes).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know - neither of them. Select in DataFrames only projects the selected columns, it is not choosing specific records so no searching algorithm is required.

To obtain specific records as you would do with the WHERE clause in standard SQL, you have to `select()` columns you are interested in and then filter them with `filter()` method.

Comment: My bad. I did not mention about the use of filter. I have updated the question. I have filtered the rows and selected the required column. I believe it works on row basis. however i want a quick search as hash search. So is it possible to create an index or hash table of it?